# Is it possible to modify an IQueryable expression manually

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, code-first, iqueryable

I'm pretty certain I know the answer is no but as a last ditch attempt I thought I'd ask the question here.

I'm using EF code first to query a table in the usual fashion

```
_context.Set<Foo>().Where(f => f.Bar == 999);
```

which creates the following expression (I've just written this so it might be wrong).

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Test] AS [Test], 
[Extent1].[Test2] AS [Test2], 
FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 19 = [Extent1].[Bar]}
```

Now, is it possible to manually modify this query to change the table name to, say, Foo10? (probably not)

Failing that, does anybody know of a way I can "late bind" the table name in code first?

You're probably wondering "Why the dirty hack?" As usual, this is a legacy issue with a database that's got some design issues and can't be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Ps. I'm aware that I could use `Database.SqlQuery` but would rather not.

Comment: why don't you have the table `Foo10` in your model as well?

Comment: Because technically its the same model spread across multiple tables. The table which your data is in varies depending on a parameter

Comment: @mjmcloug, how does it depend?

Comment: @Krizz well if a particular parameter has a value of 1 look in Foo1 if its 2 look in Foo2 and so on

Comment: @mjmcloug how many tables are there? couple of them? or loads of them?

Comment: @Krizz at the moment there are about 8... Do I feel a DTO coming on here?

Comment: @mjmcloug not exactly, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [TPT](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/) inheritance on your model?

Similar to @Krizz's answer, but you avoid using dynamic LINQ.

Using your comment:

> if a particular parameter has a value of 1 look in Foo1 if its 2 look in Foo2 and so on

So, you could do this:

```
var query = ctx
   .Foos
   .OfMyType(value)
   .Where(f => f.Bar == 999) // f.Bar is on the base/abstract entity.
   .ToList();
```

Where `OfMyType` is a custom extension method on `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OfMyType<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string value)
{
   switch (value)
   {
      case "1":
         return source.OfType<Foo1>();
      case "2":
         return source.OfType<Foo2>();
      // etc, etc
   }
}
```

Most (if not all) of the properties will be on the abstract "Foo" entity, and you create derived entities for each of the tables, which each have their own backing table.

That way, "consuming" code (e.g the ones making the queries), need not care about the different tables/Foo's, they simply pass the "magic value" to your repository (hopefully your using one), then you can silently switch to the table you want.

Would that work?

Comment: Again this looks good. I'll have to give it a go and get back to you. But again my only issue is it means generating a lot of classes which I'm trying to avoid. Gotta love legacy!

Comment: +1 Nice to simplify my approach by using what framework offers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have reasonable number of tables, I would add them all into model and create a common interface all classes will implement and then select the adequate model and use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for querying.

I am not sure if this works, haven't checked it and haven't worked with "EF code-first", but this is something I would try:

Let's say your table(s) `Foo` have fields - `Bar`, `Pub`, `X` and let `X` be the one which the respective table depends on?

Then, I would define interface:

```
interface IFoo 
{
   int Bar { get; set; }
   string Pub { get; set; }
   int X { get; set; }
}
```

Then each table will have its class in model:

```
[Table("Foo1")]
class Foo1 : IFoo 
{
   public int Bar { get; set; }
   public string Pub { get; set; }
   public int X { get; set; }
}

[Table("Foo2")]
class Foo2 : IFoo 
{
   public int Bar { get; set; }
   public string Pub { get; set; }
   public int X { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could filter them like following:

```
 IQueryable GetAdequateFoo(int X)
 {
    switch (X) // you could use reflection here to dynamically call the given Set<Foo#>()
    {
       case 1:
         return _context.Set<Foo1>();
       case 2:
         return _context.Set<Foo2>();
       default:
         return null;
    }
 }

 IFoo GetFooByBarAndX(int bar, int X)
 {
    IQueryable context = GetAdequateFoo(X);
    return context.Where("it.Bar == @0", bar).Cast<IFoo>(); 
 }
```

Comment: Ha, I'm not gonna down vote this answer, it actually a pretty clever idea to apply a factory method to EF. I'll have t have a think though as I've also got mapping classes as well so it's a lot of classes to set this up. Clever idea though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you create a new IQueryable with a new/modified expression (EF core 5.0 at the time of this writing).

```
var expression = query.Expression;

//modify your expression usually by building a new one or rebuilding using an ExpressionVisitor

var newQuery = query.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
```

Note: I was searching for editing an Expression on an IQueryable and this is the question that came first, but the details then focus on a very specific use case and the more general question hasn't been answered...

Comment: Yeah, but you're evading the real work by a simple comment. That's not an answer. How would *you* modify the expression and make it work on another table? Try, and you'll encounter all sorts of problems that you can't simply shrug off with a comment.

Comment: I know modifying expressions is complicated.  There are examples elsewhere, here I want to answer how to change the expression of an IQueryable.

Comment: No, you don't answer *how*. You only point out the not particularly secret fact that an `IQueryable` has an expression. OK, then what?